# Changing color "lamp" in other class

Tags: java, swing, graphics

**Situation:**

I made a Java application that can put a light on and off. Now I need to change the light, this must happen in the `class` *ColorLamp*. The normal "yellow" light is put in the `class` *Lamp*. The `class` *Colorlamp* is a `subclass` of the `class` *Lamp*.

**Question:**

How can I make it so that I can change the Lamp color by some code in the `class` *ColorLamp*?

### **Question Update:**

How can you change the color of the Lamp with the `class` *ColorLamp*?

---

### Code:

Here the code from the `class` *Lamp* (update):

```
public class Lamp
{
        protected Color kleur = Color.YELLOW;

    public static final boolean AAN = true;
    public static final boolean UIT = false;

    // instance variable
    protected boolean aanUit;

    // constructor
    public Lamp()
    {
        // init instance variable
        this.aanUit = UIT;
    }

    public void setAanUit(boolean aanUit)
    {
        this.aanUit = aanUit;
    }

    // switch
    public void switchAanUit()
    {
        this.aanUit = !this.aanUit;
    }

    public boolean getAanUit()
    {
        return this.aanUit;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String res = "Lamp: ";

        if (aanUit)
        {
            res = res + "AAN";
        }
        else
        {
            res = res + "UIT";
        }
        return res;
    }

    public void teken(Graphics g)
    {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));

            g2.drawOval(208, 100, 50, 50);      // ronde lamp

            g2.drawLine(220, 150, 220, 175);    // linker kant
            g2.drawLine(245, 150, 245, 175);    // rechter kant

            g2.drawLine(220, 175, 235, 200);    // linksonder hoek
            g2.drawLine(235, 200, 245, 175);    // rechtsonder hoek

            if(aanUit == true)
                {
                    ColorLamp kleurlamp = new ColorLamp();
                    g.setColor(kleurlamp.getColor());
                }
                else
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                g.fillOval(208, 100, 50, 50);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

---

Here the code of the current `class` *ColorLamp* (works, but not how it is ment):

```
public class ColorLamp extends Lamp
{
    protected Color kleur = Color.GREEN;

    public Color getColor()
    {
    return kleur;
    }
}
```

---

Possible right code `class` *ColorLamp*:

```
package lamp;

import java.awt.*;

public class ColorLamp extends Lamp
{
    protected Color kleur = Color.GREEN;
    public ColorLamp(Color kleur)
    {
    super(); 
    this.kleur = kleur;
    }
    public Color getKleur()
    {
    return this.kleur;
    }
    public void setKleur(Color kleur)
    {
    this.kleur = kleur;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
    String res = "Lamp: ";
    if(super.getAanUit())
    {
        res = res + "ÄAN";
    }
    else{
        res = res + "UIT";
    }
    return res + kleur.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You already are setting the color in that class... `this.kleur = kleur;`

Comment: @cricket_007 If it was that simple I would not ask the question. I want to change the color in the `class` ColorLamp.

Comment: @cricket_007 It must be a `subclass`, A specified lamp.

Comment: I assume you have some instance of `ColorLamp lamp = new ColorLamp(Color.XYZ)`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I know that I must make that instance, except for the Color part, the color must be defined in the ColorLamp `class`.

Comment: And I'm saying you already have defined the field `Color kluer` and the constructor accepts a `Color kluer`, and you also have a `setKluer` method, so I think the problem you need to address is how to use `teken` with that color

Comment: @cricket_007 I think you are right, how would i do that? Or don't you know? (btw. it is kleur, not kluer)

Comment: I have an idea, I just wanted to make sure that's what you wanted, and sorry, don't know Dutch(?) :)

Comment: @cricket_007 you're right, Dutch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is have all `Lamp` objects have a `Color`. The `Lamp` class itself will have `Color.Yellow`, and that cannot be changed from other classes.

```
public class Lamp
{
    protected Color kleur = Color.YELLOW;
    /// Other things...

    public void teken(Graphics g)
    {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            // Draw the lamp parts

            if(aanUit == true)
            {
                g.setColor(this.kleur); // Set color here
            }
            else
            {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            g.fillOval(208, 100, 50, 50);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

}
```

Then in `ColorLamp`, you can **remove** `private Color kleur;` and use the inherited `protected Color kleur` field.

To change the color after you draw the Lamp, you will need to `repaint` the Component.

Comment: How do I use the protected kleur field and repaint thing?

Comment: Same way you have `this.kleur`. `protected` fields are inherited in all extended classes. Also, I don't know how you have called this `teken` method, but in that class, you might have a `JPanel` that you can call `panel.repaint()`, for example.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, I can't come out of it. Hints? The teken method is called `test1`.

Comment: You may start with [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it tomorrow!

Comment: I followed the tutorial and tried a lot of things but it won't work for me. Where do I place the `ColorLamp lamp = new ColorLamp();`?

Comment: Check the "refining the design" tutorial again, please